# Show Sum of two or more columns in Y- Axis of Column Chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts, data-visualization

I am new to flex.

I am taking data from SAP and displaying in column chart in a dashboard. 
I am using an `ArrayCollection` as data provider.

This has 27 columns(fields). So i am using 27 columns charts.

However, I also have to display the summary of these in two charts.i.e. sum of 14 columns in one chart and 13 columns into other.

Is there a simple way to this? Like specifying some summation operation in data provider.

Thanks.

Ravi Kumar Singh

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly.  What you have to do is when you get the data, do the summation manually and add it to the ArrayCollection.

Comment: Hi, I searched and used stacked chart. I used two columnsets in same chart. One to represent sum of 14 columns and other 13. However thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and used stacked chart. I used two columnsets in same chart. One to represent sum of 14 columns and other 13. However thank you for your reply.